# cURL login página em ASP não autentica

Tags: php, libcurl

Já pesquisei em toda parte possível na web, mas até agora não consigo entender o que está dando errado com meu código.

É o seguinte, estou tentando acessar o portal do aluno da minha faculdade, usando cURL, meu interesse é pegar as notas de cada aluno para ser servido ao outros meios.

Meu problema está no momento de fazer o login, pois estou passando o dado de usuário e senha, mas não se autentica e me parece que não está gerando cookie de autenticação.

vou posto o código q estou usando e em seguida imagem do head da página da faculdade e o página rodando localmente.

O que quero receber é a página que exibe as notas, porém nem tô conseguindo passar a página de login.

```
$url="http://179.189.22.226/corpore.net/Login.aspx"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "txtUser=aquiUsuario&txtPass=aquiSenha&ddlAlias=CorporeRM&btnLogin=Acessar"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://179.189.22.226/corpore.net/Main.aspx?ShowMode=2&SelectedMenuIDKey=');

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

[image: Login efetuado com sucesso no site normal]

[image: Login dando errado, header retorno]

Answer (score 2):

Da vez que fiz isso tive que passar essas variáveis com underline e usei uma classe que achei na internet para fazer as requisições, pois não estava conseguindo controlar corretamente a requisição com o curl.

Segue trecho de código:

```
<?php

include 'HttpClient.class.php';

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$client = new HttpClient('intranet.somedomain.com.br');
$client->cookie_host = 'intranet.somedomain.com.br';
$client->persist_cookies = true;

$client->get('/Login.aspx');

preg_match('/<[^>]*value="(?<__VIEWSTATE>\/[a-z0-9]+)"[^>]*>/i', $client->getContent(), $params);

$client->post('/Login.aspx', array(
    '__EVENTTARGET' => "",
    '__EVENTARGUMENT' => "",
    '__VIEWSTATE' => $params['__VIEWSTATE'],
    'txtUsuario' => $email,
    'txtsenha' => $password,
    'txtNewPasswd' => '',
    'txtReenterNewPasswd' => '',
    'txtEmailLembrarSenha' => '',
    'btnLogin' => 'Entrar',
    'hdnAlteraSenha' => '0' 
));


$client->get('/engine.aspx?pg=42');
```

A lib que usei foi essa: http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/

Como esta fazendo um protótipo, se funciona-se já estava bom, eu não me preocupei muito com a lib estar desatualizada.

Nesse exemplo que passei, eu acesso a pagina de login da aplicação, pego o valor da variável view state e faço a requisição.